# Inexact Repeating alarm fires on system events

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am facing a weird behavior of the `AlarmManger`.

Six months ago, my company had published an app to Google Play. One of the app's features was to sync data from a server where users were able to perform a manual sync or to activate the auto-sync feature.

The auto-sync is an Inexact Repeating alarm and was implemented as Google describes in their [Scheduling Repeating Alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#set) tutorial.

Here is the code that enables/disables the alarm

```
public void startAlarm(Context context) {
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SyncAlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR,
            alarmIntent
    );

    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootAlarmReceiver.class);
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    Log.i("Sync", "Sync alarm started");
}

public void stopAlarm(Context context) {
    alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);

    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootAlarmReceiver.class);
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    Log.i("Sync", "Sync alarm stopped");
}
```

From AlarmReceiver

```
public class SyncAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Sync", "Auto sync started");
        context.startService(AndroidSyncService.AUTO_SYNC_INTENT(context));
    }
}
```

The feature was tested in multiple devices and was working as expected. Also, until now, none user complained that the feature was not working.

So far so good. However, 2 weeks ago a new developer joined our team and she installed the app in her [Meizu M2 Note](http://www.meizu.com/en/products/m2note/summary.html). Now this is where things get complicated.

She noticed (after some days when the 2GB free data plan was spent too fast) that the app was syncing every 5 or 6 seconds.

Our first thought was that we were not setting the alarm correctly. But, after reviewing many times the code without finding any clue of what might have been set up incorrectly we decided to download some project samples found on web and see if the same behavior would occur. Well, the `Meizu M2 Note` had exactly the same behavior. The alarm was firing randomly and too often.

After some further investigation we found that the behavior is not random. It seems that some specific actions are firing the alarm, such as when switching on/off the screen, locking/unlocking the device, switching on/off the internet connection.

Any ideas on what may cause this?

Comment: You say other devices but what about different android versions? Did you consider that?

Comment: Thats odd. That device runs 5.1. In this version of the OS, alarms minimum period is 1 minute, and lower values are rounded up to 1 minute. Check `adb shell dumpsys alarm`.

Comment: @JoxTraex We tested it in android 4, 5 and 6. I don't remember the exact versions. The device that has the problem runs 5.1 and we tested it on another device with 5.1 without showing the same behavior.

Comment: Well if they were the same version but the response of the code was different on two devices .. it sounds like it was a bad port of google's alarm changes from kitkat to 5.1.1 https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html . Possibly a kernel problem, since the kernel is responsible for waking the device at those intervals.